# Disable auto-rename of file names when opening links multiple times

Tags: firefox, file-download

When I click on a link to a `*.gz` file, Firefox asks me what to do with this file. When I click "Open with", it downloads that file to the temp directory and opens it with my archiver program. So far all works as expected.

The problem occurs when I open the link for the second time. Then, Firefox seems to notice that the file already exists in the temp directory, and silently adds a `-1` suffix before the file ending, e.g. `trace_host4137184_2d2e2211d9c0896a4f056e5cd378803a0497a6a0_2018-04-25.log-1.gz`. This is unfortunate because then the local file names are misleading: a `*.log-1` file could be the latest log file which was just downloaded twice, or it could be an older, rotated log file.

So is there a way to disable this automatic renaming mechanism?

Comment: Don't just open but instead save manually.

Comment: But I want to open it!

Comment: Well assuming they are the same files just save them and open them afterwards. That way you will save some traffic and can do whatever you want with it.